# text based adventure help and tips

Tags: text, batch-file, wait, typing, adventure

I decided to make a text based adventure and I realized I didn't know much about making one. I do, however, know that I want to make it with a batch file, just because I think it is easier to work with and share. I don't have many questions right now but I'm sure I'll come up with more as time goes on (if I decide this is fun) but right now I have two questions:

1. How do you make lines appear as if someone was typing it?
2. How do you make the line wait x seconds before going to the next process (you know for "dramatic effect")

**edit** I forgot to put the script that I need help with sorry (it's supposed to look like the "wake up neo" screen from The Matrix but I cant get the intervals smaller than 2 or hide the ping text underneath).

```
    echo h
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2
    cls
    echo he
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2
    cls
    echo hel
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2
    cls
    echo hell
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2
    cls
    echo hello
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 3
    cls
    echo hello.
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 3
    cls
    echo hello..
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 3
    cls
    echo hello...
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a Q&A site. First read some tutorial on batch programming, try some code, and come back with your code and a detailed question, we will be happy to help you then.

Comment: Try a look at the code of others batch adventures like [Dostips: 
Swords of Morovaith](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4736)

Answer (score 2):

#### Wait/Delay [[Source]](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php)

```
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul
```

5 Second Delay

- How it Works: 6 ping echos with default 1 second pause between them with loopback ip.
- `-n` cannot be less than 2 or there will be no delay.

---

#### Delay < 1 Second

```
PING 10.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 200 >nul
```

200 Millisecond Delay by using a [Private IP Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) and the timeout flag `-w`. ( only adjust the `-w` value and leave `-n` as 1 when using this method )

---

#### Great Getting Started Resources

[Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php)

[SS64](http://ss64.com/)

[DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/)

[ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/)

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390.aspx)

---

#### Example

Here is an example Typing routine that will print out each character of the message with a 200ms delay between each character.

```
@echo off
call :Typing "hello..."
exit /b 0

:Typing <Message>
setlocal
set "Message=%~1"
:TypingLoop
ping 10.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 200 >nul
<nul set /p "=%Message:~0,1%"
set "Message=%Message:~1%"
if defined Message goto TypingLoop
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Comment: That's good and but nothing I have tried can hide it is there a way you can think of that works

Comment: To hide the output of the command use an output redirect.  `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul`

Comment: thank you very much this has helped me allot. i have the first little bit of the "game" finished and i couldnt have done it with out your help thank you

Comment: @EliSchmidt  Glad to help :)  and Welcome to SO.